# Lexical token disappeared in specific mode

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have this lexer config:

```
WS
    : ((' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ | '\\' '\n') -> skip
    ;

T_QUOTED
    : '"'
    ;

T_CONFDIR_MYDIR
    : 'MyDirective' -> pushMode(mydir)
    ;

T_COMMENT
    : '#' .*? '\r'? '\n'
    ;

mode mydir;

T_MYDIRARG
    : ~([\\" ])+ -> popMode
    ;
```

And this is the input:

```
MyDirective "LiteralString"
```

When I try to parse (with Python, actually) I get this error:

```
line 4:21 token recognition error at: ' '
line 4:22 token recognition error at: '"'
line 4:23 extraneous input 'LiteralString' expecting '"'
line 5:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting T_MYDIRARG
```

It seems like if the state goes to `mydir`, then the tokens in default mode (`WS`, `T_QUOTED`) are disappeared.

Why does not lexer recognize the space and the `"` characters (as those are defined as `WS` and `T_QUOTED`)?

What would be the expected solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the `mydir` mode after the input `MyDirective`, the first char will be a space char, which the `mydir` does not recognize.

`mydir` can only recognize tokens defined in its own scope, not tokens in other scopes (also not the default scope/mode). In other words, in your case, `mydir` only recognizes `T_MYDIRARG` tokens.

Look like what you're after is something like this:

```
WS
    : ((' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ | '\\' '\n') -> skip
    ;

T_QUOTED_OPEN
    : '"' -> pushMode(mydir)
    ;

T_CONFDIR_MYDIR
    : 'MyDirective'
    ;

T_COMMENT
    : '#' .*? '\r'? '\n'
    ;

mode mydir;

T_QUOTED_CLOSE
    : '"' -> popMode
    ;

T_MYDIRARG
    : ~([\\" ])+
    ;
```

which will produce the following:

```
5 tokens:
  1    T_CONFDIR_MYDIR                'MyDirective'
  2    T_QUOTED_OPEN                  '"'
  3    T_MYDIRARG                     'LiteralString'
  4    T_QUOTED_CLOSE                 '"'
  5    EOF                            '<EOF>'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution makes the syntax parsing more complex, just think about the rule, eg:

stmnt:
    T_CONFDIR_MYDIR T_QUOTED_OPEN T_MYDIRARG T_QUOTED_CLOSE
   ;

(Hope the lines won't break... but who knows)

Thanks again.

Comment: Btw the question is still open (you wrote: "If you go into the mydir mode after the input MyDirective, the first char will be a space char, which the mydir does not recognize.") - why? Why can't "mydir" recognize the space, because there is the WS token?

Comment: the `WS` token belongs to the default mode, not the `mydir` mode

Comment: But the tokens in default mode aren't visible in any other modes?

Comment: Correct: the tokens in default mode aren't visible in any other modes.

Comment: Oh, that's new for me (and I'm really surprised now). Is there any way to make tokens visible in each mode?

Comment: @airween no, there is not.